# Убрать .html во всех файлах статичного сайта

Tags: html

Как убрать расширение `.html` в адресной строке браузера. Сайт расположен на хостинге и полностью статичен, есть также папки со вложенными html-страницами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Вариант 1

Если у вас на хостинге в качестве веб-сервера используется `Apache`, то в `.htaccess` достаточно будет прописать:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html
```

**site.ru** замените на домен вашего сайта. После этого открытие `site.ru/contacts.html` перенаправит на `site.ru/contacts`.

#### Вариант 2

Для каждого файла создать папку с соответствующим файлу названием, после переместить в эту папку одноименный файл и переименовать его в `index.html`.

Comment: как можно узнать используется ли Apache?

Comment: @easy в корне сайта должен быть файл .htaccess. Или же саппорт хостинга спрашивайте.

Comment: если у меня нет на хостинге файла htaccess я могу его создать сам ?

Comment: всё настроил, делая ваш код, у меня выходила ошибка и страницы не открывались, выводила такой путь, без .htaccess обычно так мойсайт.ру/новости.хтмл, когда добавил ваш .htaccess и в нем заменил сайт.ру на свой сайт выводило ошибку и было "мойсайт.ру/мойсайт.ру/новости", я не совсем понял как это работает но вот, когда я удалил из кода .htaccess свой сайт, все страницы открывались и .html убирался, я не совсем понял как работает это но вот. .htaccess добавил в public_html своего .ht не было на хостинге, создавал новый.

Answer (score 0):

Если на хостинге нет доступа к HTACCESS то никак... а если есть копай в эту сторону

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```