# Как запретить в robots ссылки у которых на конце .html?

Tags: html, .htaccess, оптимизация-сайтов, robots.txt

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. В интернете не смог найти примера-решения.

Есть сайт который раньше был статическим, теперь он динамический на php и в конце ссылок отсутствует расширение **.html**, но в индекс то попадают то выпадают старые ссылки с этим расширением. Хочу запретить это в роботсе, кто знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /~user/site/

или...

каждый .html выборочно:

> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /~user/site/foo.html

Источник: https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку в тегах указан `.htaccess` рискнуть предложить такой вариант:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Так будут работать старые ссылки, а робот постепенно перенесет все в новый формат.
В варианте robot.txt старые ссылки останутся не рабочими.

Есть еще вариант:
[Убрать .html во всех файлах статичного сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811423/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0)